# How to populate data from select dropdown so that data of particular id will be displayed to the main page

Tags: html, django

I have created a dropdown selector and want data to be fetched from the database according to that.

I have two models: `Cuisine` and `Dish`. I have taken all the cuisines in my dropdown selector (e.g. Indian, British, Frech, etc.) and want to fetch all the dishes from the database according to it.

For example, when I select Indian then all the dished that are associated with it should be fetched so that I can display it on the home page.

model.py

```
class Cuisine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 



class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes_pics')
    description = models.TextField()
    required_time_to_cook = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Cuisine,Dish

def select_cuisine(request):
    dish_id = Dish.objects.get(pk = 1)
    cuisine_id = Cuisine.objects.filter(cuisine=cuisine_id)
    return render(request, 'cookbook/base.html', {'cuisine_type' : cuisine_id})



def home(request):
    context = {
        'dishes' : Dish.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'cookbook/home.html',context)
```

index.html

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select Cuisine</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    {% for type  in cuisine_type %}
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ type.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please add screenshot of you database sample data

Comment: Hi,sample data is according to the fields of the model.For example first I created an object of model Cuisine(eg,1st create an object of Cuisine and insert the given fields in model Dish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name ='Indian'
cuisine_id = Cuisine.objects.filter(name=name).values('id')
dishes = Dish.objects.filter(cuisine_id=cuisine_id).all()
```

Here we first select `cuisine_id` from `Cuisine` model where `name='Indian'`. Next Select all details from `Dish` where `cuisine_id` of the `Dish` is equal to `cuisine_id` of the `Cuisine` model.